# How to put text from spinner to file?

Tags: android, string, text, spinner, sharedpreferences

I have this problem. I read with BufferedReader text from one system file, this text contains for example 5 WORDS, but in another case it can contain less or more words, then I put this text (these words) to ONE string and save that string to shared preferences. Then I make spinner from this string,

Code here:

```
Spinner spinner = new Spinner(this);
    ArrayAdapter<String> spinnerArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, yourString.split(" "));
    spinner.setAdapter(spinnerArrayAdapter);
```

And now if for example spinner contains 5 options (5 words) and user select some of these words, I need to put this word to one system file. **I use echo command for insertion. So the best thing would be if I could save chosen word from spinner to shared preferences as string.** I use if(possition==0) for selection in normal spinner, but I think it's not possible to use it in this case.

**Could anybody help me?**

Comment: Please be clear . Couldn't understand what are u trying to say ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can get selected text by writing this line of code

```
               spinner.getSelectedItem().toString();

                SharedPreferences pref = getSharedPreferences(
                        "Preferences", 0);
                SharedPreferences.Editor edit = pref.edit();
                edit.putString("ABC", spinner.getSelectedItem().toString());
                edit.commit();
```

Comment: by this you'll get the name of selected words from spinner. so that you can use that string for shared preferences.

Answer (score 0):

not getting your complete idea what you want to do...
but i think you want to get text which is selected in the spinner, then split your string in one array pass this array in your spinner adapter.

After that use onItemSelection method, In this method u will get position and fetch the corresponding record from your array.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the getPosition() method on the ArrayAdapter.

spinnerArrayAdapter.getPosition(savedstring);

If the saved string is in the array second time in then you can call setSelection() to that position otherwise let the user know (e.g. via Toast) that the previous selection is no longer valid.